# rendering when third party cookies are disabled/no localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, google-chrome-extension, plugins

i'm currently working on a chrome extension.

i want to show a simple div, or redirect to an error page when third party cookies are disabled. I'm able to use an alert to tell the user to enable third party cookies with

```
   try {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      console.log('cookies ENABLED');
    }
   } catch (err) {
    alert('Please enable third-party cookies');
    return <Redirect push to="/error" />;
   }
```

But i'd love for it to be an actual component or to redirect to component. So far I haven't found anything that works, because it's just blank, so i'm not able to do much.

Comment: which version of react & react-router-dom are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since `React >= 16.8+`, you can use `useNavigate()` hook and redirect programmatically.

```
// at the top-level
const navigate = useNavigate();

try {
    //
} catch (err) {
    navigate('/error');
}
```

Continue reading [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)